# Why doesn't array of elements return from xml?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

Why doesn't the following return the two string `node` values?

```
string xmlContent = "<ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.23.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsft.com/2003/10/SerializationArrays><string>value1</string><string>value2</string></ArrayOfstring>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent);
var list = doc.Root.Elements("string")
           .Select(element => element.Value)
           .ToList();
```

list count is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the node `string` appears to be in `http://schemas.microsft.com/2003/10/SerializationArrays"` namespace,

So you will need to attach `XNamespace` first. Something like this

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsft.com/2003/10/SerializationArrays";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent);
var list = doc.Root.Elements(ns + "string")
           .Select(element => element.Value)
           .ToList();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace(v=vs.110).aspx